# Query of records based on relationships

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have an object Contract that has a look-up to another object Indexationtype. I have another object IndexationEntry that has master-detail to Indexationtype. Now I would like to get the value of the percentage field in the IndexationEntry onto Contract based on the yer fields. The year in the IndexationEntry matches Year in Contract. How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

From Contract "up" to IndexationType__c, then "down" to IndexationEntry__c?

If there's no direct link between them it's not going to be pretty. One way would be something like this

```
SELECT Id, Name,
    (SELECT Id, ContractNumber FROM Contracts__r WHERE Year__c = '2021'),
    (SELECT Id, Percent__c FROM IndexationEntries__r WHERE Year__c = '2021')
FROM IndexationType__c
```

You'd have to run it once for each year. Or (since you tagged it Apex) maybe you can prepare the reference data a bit, query Indexation Types + Entries and build something like `Map<Id, Map<Integer, IndexationEntry__c>>` (1st key is by Indexation Type Id, then by year). Query them, populate the Map, then loop through your contracts and use map.get() to fetch your values.